# Linear Algebra Book with good proofs

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation

I'm taking a first course in Linear Algebra as an undergraduate. 
I started reading Linear Algebra-A Geometric Approach by S Kumaresan.
I've been wondering if the proofs are too rigorous and formal and long.
I would like to know if Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right would be a better book to follow.

Comment: I am a huge fan of Adler's Linear Algebra Done Right and would really recommend going for this one! However, Adler's book is for a second course in Linear Algebra and so you might find it goes too fast if you haven't done any before. Either way it's definitely worth owning a copy.

Comment: I've done two chapters from Kumaresan's book so I have a rough idea of the concepts.I just wish the proofs were more intuitive.Should I be looking at simpler intuitive proofs or more formal long ones if I want to learn the subject well? Thank you!

Comment: Is it a good idea to couple Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra with LADR? And give up Kumaresan's book altogether?

Comment: I would give up on Kumaresan, if you look on amazon it has 59% 1 star reviews. I had a quick look through and it's not how I would want to learn linear algebra. LADR and Strangs book together should be all you need.

Comment: Adler? Do you mean, Axler?

Comment: Woops yes Axler is right, Thanks!

Comment: Okay, will do that.Thank you so much!

Comment: I think Strang's linear algebra books do a great job of conveying intuition and showing how simple/easy linear algebra is. Then another book such as Friedberg can develop the theory for abstract vector spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I agree wholeheartedly with the commenters; Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right is the best linear algebra book I have read, and one of the best books ever.